# Rutina no obtiene resultadoas al ser automatizada pero sí cuando lo ejecuto manualmente

Tags: excel, vba, find

saludos a todos;

Estoy haciendo una subrutina que me busca una coincidencia con cierto texto (variable) en una columna especifica, luego de encontrar al menos 1 coincidencia copia un rango de texto a otro libro.

El problema es que, si ésta rutina lo invoco desde otra o por enlace (automatizado) no encuentra ninguna coincidencia, cuando lo realiza manulamente desde VBA funcionan perfectamente.

Espero me puedan ayudar a encontrar el inconveniente o sugerir por dónde puede estar el inconveniente, estoy comenzado con vba en excel y la verdad ya no encuentro solución buscando información en la red ni haciendo mis pruebas de descarte, por si es necesario detallo el código:

```
Sub elFiltro():
Dim contador1 As Integer
'Declarando variables
lastRow4 = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUlt = Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
archTrab = Workbooks("VerifCorre.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("C4").Value
nombArch = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MMM-DD")

''Eliminar luego de probar
Workbooks(nombArch & ".xlsx").Activate 'Eliminar luego
Sheets(1).Name = "Res." 'Eliminar luego

'Seleccionando libro de origen
Workbooks(archTrab).Activate
Range("D1").Select

'Ubica el cursor a la celda A1 y activar autofiltro
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

Dim tipComp(1 To 4) As String
tipComp(1) = "BN0"
tipComp(2) = "BV0"
tipComp(3) = "FN0"
tipComp(4) = "FA0"

Dim comp As Variant
For Each comp In tipComp

    For contador = 4 To 1 Step -1
        datBuscado = comp & contador

        Set busDato = Range("$C$1", Cells(lastRowUlt, 4)).Find(datBuscado, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)

        If busDato Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No hay coincidencias con: " & datBuscado

        Else
            MsgBox "Hay al menos 1 coincidencia con " & datBuscado & " , procederemos a incluir información encontrada"

            Workbooks(nombArch & ".xlsx").Activate
            Worksheets.Add.Name = datBuscado
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

            'Seleccionando libro de origen
            Workbooks(archTrab).Activate
            Range("D1").Select

            'Aplicando filtro en columna 3 (C) con el criterio datBuscado
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1", Cells(lastRowUlt, 29)).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=datBuscado

            Workbooks(archTrab).Worksheets(1).Range("$A$1", Cells(lastRow4, 5)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(nombArch & ".xlsx").Worksheets(datBuscado).Range("A1")
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

            'Eliminando columna innecesaria
            Workbooks(nombArch & ".xlsx").Activate
            Sheets(datBuscado).Select
            Columns("B:B").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

            'Adicionando títulos a las columnas
            Range("B1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "b"
            Range("C1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "c"
            Range("D1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "d"
            Range("E1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "e"

            'Guardando cambios
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

            'Volviendo a libro origen
            Windows(archTrab).Activate

            'Quitando el criterio del filtro (mostrando toda la información)
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

        End If
    Next contador

Next comp

Workbooks(nombArch & ".xlsx").Activate

Sheets("Res.").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)

'Guardando cambios
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una instruction On Error y ver el mensaje:

```
 Sub elFiltro()
    On Error GoTo fallo
    ....

   'Guardando cambios
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Exit Sub
 fallo:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia. Pero leyendo vi que el tema pude ser por el uso más de lo absolutamente neceasario de Select y Activate, según el tema "Avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE"

Answer (score 0):

finalmente tube que separar en módulos distintos secciones del código para llamarlo con un "Call" y dejó de mostrarme éste error.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/342426)